# HTML Tool to determine where style is coming from

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an ASP.NET page where I need to figure out where the style for a textbox is coming from.  There are several style sheets defined for the page and I want to be able to use some sort of tool / editor that will tell me what styles were used and from what file(s) to render the textbox.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use Firefox with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/1843) and inspect the Text-box. Firebug is the most useful tool to do exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

In IE you can use the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359). But I'm a fan of FireBug for FireFox.

From comments: [Bernard Chhun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48500/bernard-chhun) recommended [FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) as an alternative to IE Dev Toolbar. It also works for Opera and Safari too.

Comment: IE Developer Toolbar is still the best dev tool with debugbar to inspect IE though. and there's always Firebug Lite but it's not quite like the original firebug :)

Comment: FireBug Lite is quite neat (support for opera and safari too!) I hadn't heard of that, I'll add it to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have developer tools (build-in or as extension) that can show you the [cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) of the applied rules.

For Firefox there is the [Firebug extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843), Safari (WebKit) has [Web Inspector](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/ProposedWebInspectorUIRefresh), Opera has [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) and for the Internet Explorer there is the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038).

Answer (score 0):

The [web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) for Firefox has CSS and element inspectors which I find very useful.

You can also modify the CSS in the browser so you can tweak layout without going back to your IDE